# Driving record elements through procedures from different processes in VHDL

Tags: vhdl

In my architecture I define a signal of some record type. Each of the record elements is driven in one process only.

The whole record signal is passed to procedures. The procedures will later be placed in a package. Passing the record as type "inout" leeds to all accessed record elements resolving to 'X'.

The code runs in Modelsim and is only for verification (no synthesis needed).

Driving the record elements directly works.

Minimal example; Architecture header:

```
-- Record type
type tr_Data is record
    r1_A    : std_logic;
    r1_B    : std_logic;
end record;

-- Signal definition and initialization
signal sr_Data  : tr_Data   := (
    r1_A    => '0',
    r1_B    => '1'
);
```

Architecture body:

```
-- This process only modifies sr_Data.r1_A
prcss_A: process
    procedure proc_Modify_A(signal d: inout tr_Data) is
    begin
        d.r1_A  <= not d.r1_A;
    end procedure;
begin
    wait for 1 us;
    --sr_Data.r1_A  <= not sr_Data.r1_A;    -- This works
    proc_Modify_A(sr_Data);                 -- This works not
    wait for 1 us;
    wait;
end process;

-- This process only modifies sr_Data.r1_B
prcss_B: process
    procedure proc_Modify_B(signal d: inout tr_Data) is
    begin
        d.r1_B  <= not d.r1_B;
    end procedure;
begin
    wait for 1.5 us;
    --sr_Data.r1_B  <= not sr_Data.r1_B;    -- This works
    proc_Modify_B(sr_Data);                 -- This works not
    wait for 1 us;
    wait;
end process;
```

This is the Result in Modelsim:

[image: Modelsim simulation result]

I'm not sure, if this is possible at all. Maybe there are also better solutions to my problem.

Thank's for the help!

Comment: I'm not sure but I suppose that when you change sr_Data in the process A, the record is reassigned in his totality. So for r1_A it takes the new value but for r1_B it infers a latch in order to memorise the last value. You can try to change the waiting time of one of the two process in order to validate or to invalidate this theory.

Comment: @Gautitho: Thanks for the idea, this might help. I changed the time as you suggested and updated the posting. It seems, that it is not changed in total but already the first signal resolves to 'X'.

Comment: @Gautitho, this is simulation code. There are no latches infered anywhere. Latches are a hardware concept and this is running in modelsim that uses no hardware. The error is because the procedures drive the entire record hence causing multiple drivers.

Comment: @Tricky, I could have been more clear in my explanation. Actually it is not a latch, it's a latch behaviour. When the record is partially affected, the remaining signals are memorized.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for all the detailed informations. I learned a lot through that.

Based on your answers I found a solution. For my purpose, it is to use a resolved type and init it at the beginning of each process as Giampietro Seu suggested. This also enables me to put non-resolved types like integer, time etc. in the record.

Here is the full reproducable minimal example.

Entity:

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.std_logic_1164.all;
use IEEE.numeric_std.all;

use work.pkg_Minimal.all;

entity eMinimalExample is
end entity;

    architecture aMinimal of eMinimalExample is
        -- Signal of resolved subtype
        signal sr_Data : rtr_Data;
    begin

    -- This process only modifies sr_Data.r1_A / ri_A
    prcss_A: process
    begin
        proc_Init_A(sr_Data);    -- Only needed once
        wait for 1 us;
        proc_Modify_A(sr_Data);
        wait for 1 us;
        wait;
    end process;

    -- This process only modifies sr_Data.r1_B / ri_B
    prcss_B: process
    begin
        proc_Init_B(sr_Data);    -- Only needed once
        wait for 1.5 us;
        proc_Modify_B(sr_Data);
        wait for 1 us;
        wait;
    end process;

    prcss_Monitor: process (sr_Data)
    begin
        report
            LF & HT &
            "sr_Data.r1_A = " & std_logic'image(sr_Data.r1_A) &
            LF & HT &
            "sr_Data.r1_B = " & std_logic'image(sr_Data.r1_B) &
            LF & HT &
            "sr_Data.ri_A = " & integer'image(sr_Data.ri_A)   &
            LF & HT &
            "sr_Data.ri_B = " & integer'image(sr_Data.ri_B);
    end process;

end architecture;
```

Package:

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.std_logic_1164.all;
use IEEE.numeric_std.all;

package pkg_Minimal is

    -- Record type
    type tr_Data is record
        r1_A    : std_logic;
        ri_A    : integer;
        r1_B    : std_logic;
        ri_B    : integer;
    end record;

    -- Array of record
    type ta_Data is array(natural range <>) of tr_Data;

    -- Resolution function for record
    function f_resolve_Data (ca_Data: in ta_Data) return tr_Data;

    -- Resolved record subtype
    subtype rtr_Data is f_resolve_Data tr_Data;

    -- Init A with init values and B with recessive values
    procedure proc_Init_A   (signal d: inout rtr_Data);
    -- Init B with init values and A with recessive values
    procedure proc_Init_B   (signal d: inout rtr_Data);
    -- Modify A only
    procedure proc_Modify_A (signal d: inout rtr_Data);
    -- Modify B only
    procedure proc_Modify_B (signal d: inout rtr_Data);

end package;

package body pkg_Minimal is

    -- Record init values
    constant cr_Data_Init : tr_Data := (
        r1_A    => '0',
        ri_A    => 10,
        r1_B    => '1',
        ri_B    => 20
    );

    -- Recessive values for resolution function
    constant cr_Data_Recessive : tr_Data := (
        r1_A    => 'Z',
        ri_A    => integer'low, -- Lowest value is burned,
        r1_B    => 'Z',         -- we can't use it anymore
        ri_B    => integer'low
    );

    -- Resolution function for record
    function f_resolve_Data (constant ca_Data: in ta_Data) return tr_Data is
        variable vr_Data : tr_Data := cr_Data_Recessive;
    begin
        for i in ca_Data'range loop
            if cr_Data_Recessive.r1_A /= ca_Data(i).r1_A then
                vr_Data.r1_A := ca_Data(i).r1_A;
            end if;
            if cr_Data_Recessive.r1_B /= ca_Data(i).r1_B then
                vr_Data.r1_B := ca_Data(i).r1_B;
            end if;
            if cr_Data_Recessive.ri_A /= ca_Data(i).ri_A then
                vr_Data.ri_A := ca_Data(i).ri_A;
            end if;
            if cr_Data_Recessive.ri_B /= ca_Data(i).ri_B then
                vr_Data.ri_B := ca_Data(i).ri_B;
            end if;
        end loop;
        return vr_Data;
    end function;

    procedure proc_Init_A(signal d: inout rtr_Data) is
    begin
        d <= cr_Data_Recessive;
        d.r1_A <= cr_Data_Init.r1_A;
        d.ri_A <= cr_Data_Init.ri_A;
    end procedure;

    procedure proc_Init_B(signal d: inout rtr_Data) is
    begin
        d <= cr_Data_Recessive;
        d.r1_B <= cr_Data_Init.r1_B;
        d.ri_B <= cr_Data_Init.ri_B;
    end procedure;

    procedure proc_Modify_A(signal d: inout rtr_Data) is
    begin
        d.r1_A <= not d.r1_A;
        d.ri_A <= d.ri_A + 1;
    end procedure;

    procedure proc_Modify_B(signal d: inout rtr_Data) is
    begin
        d.r1_B <= not d.r1_B;
        d.ri_B <= d.ri_B + 1;
    end procedure;

end package body;
```

Output:

```
 ** Note: 
    sr_Data.r1_A = '0'
    sr_Data.r1_B = '1'
    sr_Data.ri_A = 10
    sr_Data.ri_B = 20
    Time: 0 ps  Iteration: 0  Instance: /eminimalexample
 ** Note: 
    sr_Data.r1_A = '1'
    sr_Data.r1_B = '1'
    sr_Data.ri_A = 11
    sr_Data.ri_B = 20
    Time: 1 us  Iteration: 1  Instance: /eminimalexample
 ** Note: 
    sr_Data.r1_A = '1'
    sr_Data.r1_B = '0'
    sr_Data.ri_A = 11
    sr_Data.ri_B = 21
    Time: 1500 ns  Iteration: 1  Instance: /eminimalexample
```

Answer (score 3):

This question demonstrates why providing a [minimal, complete, and verifiable exampe](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) is desirable for code errors (instead of snippets as here).

Creating a MCVe:

```vhdl
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;

entity record_process is
end entity;

architecture foo of record_process is
    type tr_Data is record
        r1_A:   std_logic;
        r1_B:   std_logic;
    end record;
    signal sr_Data: tr_Data := (r1_A => '0', r1_B  => '1');
begin
prcss_A: -- This process only modifies sr_Data.r1_A
    process
        procedure proc_Modify_A(signal d: inout tr_Data) is
        begin
            d.r1_A  <= not d.r1_A;
        end procedure;
    begin
        wait for 1 us;
        -- sr_Data.r1_A  <= not sr_Data.r1_A;    -- This works
        proc_Modify_A(sr_Data);                 -- This works not
        wait for 1 us;
        wait;
    end process;

prcss_B: -- This process only modifies sr_Data.r1_B
    process
        procedure proc_Modify_B(signal d: inout tr_Data) is
        begin
            d.r1_B  <= not d.r1_B;
        end procedure;
    begin
        wait for 1.5 us;
        --sr_Data.r1_B  <= not sr_Data.r1_B;    -- This works
        proc_Modify_B(sr_Data);                 -- This works not
        wait for 1 us;
        wait;
    end process;
MONITOR:
    process (sr_Data)
    begin
        report 
            LF & HT &
            "sr_Data.r1_A = " & std_logic'image(sr_Data.r1_A) &
            LF & HT &
            "sr_Data.r1_B = " & std_logic'image(sr_Data.r1_B);
    end process;
end architecture;
```

we see reported behavior that matches the OP's waveform:

```
record_process.vhdl:44:9:@0ms:(report note):
    sr_Data.r1_A = '0'
    sr_Data.r1_B = '1'
record_process.vhdl:44:9:@1us:(report note):
    sr_Data.r1_A = 'X'
    sr_Data.r1_B = '1'
record_process.vhdl:44:9:@1500ns:(report note):
    sr_Data.r1_A = 'X'
    sr_Data.r1_B = 'X'
```

The 'X's are caused by the way drivers are associated with subprogram actual parameters:

IEEE Std 1076-2008
4.2 Subprogram declarations
4.2.2.3 Signal parameters

> A process statement contains a driver for each actual signal associated with a formal signal parameter of mode out or inout in a subprogram call. Similarly, a subprogram contains a driver for each formal signal parameter of mode **out** or **inout** declared in its subprogram specification.
>
> For a signal parameter of mode **inout** or **out**, the driver of an actual signal is associated with the corresponding driver of the formal signal parameter at the start of each call. Thereafter, during the execution of the subprogram body, an assignment to the driver of a formal signal parameter is equivalent to an assignment to the driver of the actual signal.

10.7 Procedure call statement

> For each formal parameter of a procedure, a procedure call shall specify exactly one corresponding actual parameter. This actual parameter is specified either explicitly, by an association element (other than the actual open) in the association list or, in the absence of such an association element, by a default expression (see 6.5.2).

There's a driver for the actual associated in whole, here a signal of a record type.

(This also tells you Tricky's answer is valid, which reduces the actual to an element of the whole.)

**There's another possible solution**
Drop the parameter list:

```vhdl
architecture fum of record_process is
    type tr_Data is record
        r1_A:   std_logic;
        r1_B:   std_logic;
    end record;
    signal sr_Data: tr_Data := (r1_A => '0', r1_B  => '1');
begin
prcss_A: -- This process only modifies sr_Data.r1_A
    process
        procedure proc_Modify_A is
        begin
            sr_Data.r1_A  <= not sr_Data.r1_A;
        end procedure;
    begin
        wait for 1 us;
        -- sr_Data.r1_A  <= not sr_Data.r1_A;    -- This works
        proc_Modify_A;                           -- This works not
        wait for 1 us;
        wait;
    end process;

prcss_B: -- This process only modifies sr_Data.r1_B
    process
        procedure proc_Modify_B is
        begin
            sr_Data.r1_B  <= not sr_Data.r1_B;
        end procedure;
    begin
        wait for 1.5 us;
        --sr_Data.r1_B  <= not sr_Data.r1_B;    -- This works
        proc_Modify_B;                          -- This works not
        wait for 1 us;
        wait;
    end process;
MONITOR:
    process (sr_Data)
    begin
        report 
            LF & HT &
            "sr_Data.r1_A = " & std_logic'image(sr_Data.r1_A) &
            LF & HT &
            "sr_Data.r1_B = " & std_logic'image(sr_Data.r1_B);
    end process;
end architecture;
```

which produces:

```
record_process.vhdl:89:9:@0ms:(report note):
    sr_Data.r1_A = '0'
    sr_Data.r1_B = '1'
record_process.vhdl:89:9:@1us:(report note):
    sr_Data.r1_A = '1'
    sr_Data.r1_B = '1'
record_process.vhdl:89:9:@1500ns:(report note):
    sr_Data.r1_A = '1'
    sr_Data.r1_B = '0'
```

without any driver conflicts, lacking multiple drivers (14.7.2 Drivers) requiring resolution (14.7.3.4 Signal update) during simulation.

14.7.2 Drivers

> Every signal assignment statement in a process statement defines a set of *drivers* for certain scalar signals. There is a single driver for a given scalar signal S in a process statement, provided that there is at least one signal assignment statement in that process statement and that the longest static prefix of the target signal of that signal assignment statement denotes S or denotes a composite signal of which S is a subelement. Each such signal assignment statement is said to be associated with that driver. Execution of a signal assignment statement affects only the associated driver(s).

The longest static prefix is defined in 8. Names:

8.1 General

> A *static signal name* is a static name that denotes a signal. The *longest static prefix* of a signal name is the name itself, if the name is a static signal name; otherwise, it is the longest prefix of the name that is a static signal name. ...

where the longest static prefix now includes record elements as opposed to actual signals of a record type associated in whole.

This is possible because a subprogram is a sequence of statements (4.2 Subprogram bodies) and the procedures are declared within the scope of the declaration of `sr_Data` (12.1 Declarative region, 12.2 Scope of declarations, 12.3 Visibility).

Answer (score 0):

The error is here because the procedures take in a record type. When this happens, they create a driver on the entire record, not just the elements driven internally. Hence you have multiple drivers because the same signal is driven from multiple processes.

If you want to drive only the elements, make the procedures take an inout of std_logic type and only pass in the signal record elements. This way, each process is only driving a single element of the record.

```
-- This process only modifies sr_Data.r1_A
prcss_A: process
    procedure proc_Modify_A(signal d: inout std_logic) is
    begin
        d  <= not d;
    end procedure;
begin
    wait for 1 us;
    --sr_Data.r1_A  <= not sr_Data.r1_A;    -- This works
    proc_Modify_A(sr_Data.r1_A);                 -- This works not
    wait for 1 us;
    wait;
end process;

-- This process only modifies sr_Data.r1_B
prcss_B: process
    procedure proc_Modify_B(signal d: inout std_logic) is
    begin
        d  <= not d;
    end procedure;
begin
    wait for 1.5 us;
    --sr_Data.r1_B  <= not sr_Data.r1_B;    -- This works
    proc_Modify_B(sr_Data.r1_B);                 -- This works not
    wait for 1 us;
    wait;
end process;
```

Comment: If it would create a driver on the whole record, I would expect to become both record elements 'X' after 1.5 us. Your solution is a possible workaround but I would like to pass the record, if possible in any way.

Comment: This is normal that the X comes after on B because B is not modified before 1.5 us. It is memorized when A is affected so there is no conflict (Before 1.5 us, process_A sets r1_B to 1 and process_B sets r1_B too)

Comment: Ok, now I get it. So using "inout" for the record is obviously not possible. Unless there aren't any magic keywords I need to think of another solution. Using Trickys approach is not desireable because in reality the record is more complex and specifying all used signals for each procedure whould blow up the code too much.

Answer (score 0):

No time now for an explanation but the following solution should achieve exactly what you are asking for:

Architecture header:

```vhdl
-- Record type
type tr_Data is record
    r1_A    : std_logic;
    r1_B    : std_logic;
end record;

constant TR_DATA_INIT : tr_Data   := (
    r1_A    => 'Z',
    r1_B    => 'Z'
);

-- Signal definition and initialization
signal sr_Data  : tr_Data   := (
    r1_A    => '0',
    r1_B    => '1'
);
```

Architecture body:

```vhdl
-- This process only modifies sr_Data.r1_A
prcss_A: process
    procedure proc_keep_A(signal d: inout tr_Data) is
    begin
        d      <= TR_DATA_INIT;        
        d.r1_A <= d.r1_A;
    end procedure;

    procedure proc_Modify_A(signal d: inout tr_Data) is
    begin
        d.r1_A <= not d.r1_A;
    end procedure;
begin
    proc_keep_A(sr_Data); -- needed only at the very beginning of the process
    wait for 1 us;
    --sr_Data.r1_A  <= not sr_Data.r1_A;    -- This works
    proc_Modify_A(sr_Data);                 -- This works too
    wait for 1 us;
    wait;
end process;

-- This process only modifies sr_Data.r1_B
prcss_B: process
    procedure proc_keep_B(signal d: inout tr_Data) is
    begin
        d       <= TR_DATA_INIT; 
        d.r1_B  <= d.r1_B;
    end procedure;

    procedure proc_Modify_B(signal d: inout tr_Data) is
    begin
        d.r1_B  <= not d.r1_B;
    end procedure;
begin
     proc_keep_B(sr_Data); -- needed only at the very beginning of the process
    wait for 1.5 us;
    --sr_Data.r1_B  <= not sr_Data.r1_B;    -- This works
    proc_Modify_B(sr_Data);                 -- This works too
    wait for 1 us;
    wait;
end process;
```